# Framing small basement wall, but stairs don't leave space for foam insulation

Tags: framing, basement-insulation

I'm working on finishing my basement, and I'm not sure what the best approach is for framing this short section of wall so that the stair drywall transitions smoothly into the basement wall.

This house was built roughly 10 years ago, it should be waterproofed on the outside.

I have 2" foam for the rest of the basement, but there's no chance of fitting it in here behind the new framing.

I'm currently leaning towards building a frame without foam behind, then cutting the foam board to slot them in between the studs.

Is there a better approach that I should take?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most basements it is the top third of the wall where insulation does the most good.  For that small section could 1 inch insulation do?

Comment: Are you framing the wall with 2x4's?  If so, you could use 2x3's for that small section and put 1" foam board behind the 2x3's.  Or do what you suggested and just cut the foam board to fit between the 2x4's.  Or some combination thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that 1" of insulation between the studs is fine and you don't need more there but if you really want more, put a handrail on the wall down the stairs and have the end of the rail butt up against the return of the new thicker wall at the bottom.  It will look intentional.  Make the wall even more than two inches, make it just enough to accommodate the end of the handrail.   If you add hangings and/or flat sconces on the wall down the stairs and nothing on the new wall, it will all come together to make the whole wall including your new thicker one look more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation when I finished my basement. I asked the AHJ about that and they were perfectly fine with putting as much insulation as would fit while leaving the required 36" for the stairs. For me it ended being 3/4" foam boards glued to the concrete and 1/4" drywall glued to the foam. In theory the drywall should also be fastened but I didn't have room for furring strips and didn't relish fastening into the concrete through the foam board. The only saving grace is the stair stringer is butted against the drywall. It held up perfectly fine for 6 years.